# calling a method exactly after a delay

Tags: android

I want a method to be exactly called after some time (1 min for example)

the code below is wrong implementation :

```
musicPlayer.setOnPlaylistAudioChangedListener((playlist , currentAudioIndex) -> {

        if(playlist.getCurrentIndex()%3 == 0 && playlist.getCurrentIndex()!=0  )
           new Handler().postDelayed(this::myMethod,60000);
```

I have listView that plays Audio and some callbacks to control events
lets say a user clicks the listView in position 6 shortly after position 3
then myMethod() will be called twice witout the 1 min delay
is there any way to enforce delay even if the user clicks listView in those exact same positions
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for the second tap, you don't want it to have a 1min delay.  You want it to have a 2min delay.  SO you'll need to keep track of the number of sounds queued up, and delay the next tap for 60000*number_queued.  And when one plays you'll need to reduce the number queued.